# URL Encoding Strings that aren't valid URIs

Tags: java, url-encoding

I'm not sure I understand the URI object completely to do this properly.  I want to be able to convert a string into a url-encoded string.  For example, I have a servlet acting as a file handler and I need to specify the file name in the header -

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + new URI(filename).toUrl());
```

As expected, I get a `URISyntaxException` because the string I'm encoding isn't in proper URI form.

How can I encode **strings** instead of URLs?

I can't get the results I want using the depreciated URLEncoder because it replaces " " with "+" instead of "%20".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does your filename look like ?

Comment: It's the spaces it has trouble with.  Let's say I upload a file called "hello world.txt" when I download it back I'll get "hello+world.txt".  I'm being nitpicky as this point but it irked me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `URLEncoder` and simply replace all `+` with `%20`.

Also, `URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)` is not deprecated.

You could also use [org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encodeUri](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/branches/conversation/org.springframework.web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.java).

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, I thought it was the encode() method in general.  It's a bummer but it looks like I'll have to replace the + with %20 as you suggested... for some reason it doesn't feel elegant.

Comment: Added a more elegant alternative.

Comment: since I already have Spring loaded this should work well too.  I used your solution to encode it then found out that it served the file up with the encoded characters... when really I just needed to wrap my plain string in quotes.  O_o

Answer (score 2):

URLEncoder isn't for URLs, curiously enough, it is really for URL *arguments* and other things that need application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME-encoding. The easiest way I have found to URL-encode an arbitrary string 's' is `new URI(null, s, null).toASCIIString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use `new File( filename ).toURI().toURL()`. This will create the correct encoding for a file name. It also works for relative file names and files that don't exist. Actually this construct doesn't perform any file system access.

Comment: This worked as you mentioned but it gave the full path to the file.  A little lastIndexOf magic and it would have worked out just the same.  Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use `java.net.URLEncoder`

for example

```
String s = "somestuff@%#$%^3<<>>";
String encoded_string = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Doesn't process spaces correctly for URLs, only for URL arguments.