# How can I map unicode symbols to a simpler latin script equivalent in Java

Tags: java, unicode, normalize

I want to map graphical/symbol characters to a simpler Java alternative where possible, for example:

- U1E36 latin capital letter l with dot below -> L
- U25B6 Black Right-Pointing Triangle -> >
- U25C0 Black Left-Pointing Triangle -> <
- U25B2 Black UP-Pointing Triangle -> ^

My problem is I don't know what all the characters are so although it is technically easy enough to map the specific characters above it is difficult to do for every one, there could be hundreds.

I already have this code for **removing** accents ecetera

```
public static final Pattern DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS
        = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");


private static String stripDiacritics(String str) {
    str = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    str = DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
    return str;
}
```

So I was wondering if there was something similar to help me with these symbol characters, note I don't want to ever remove them just replace with a simpler representation.

Comment: Per comment elsewhere, "The point is to provide a representation of the value that can be used in a filename so that is is more portable" -- look at an [URLEncoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230693/url-encoding-strings-that-arent-valid-uris).

Comment: Thanks but thats not what Imean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Lucene filter that attempts to do what I'm trying to do by looking at each char with a unicode value greater than \u0080 and seeing if it has a mapping to a simpler character via a massive case statement

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/2.9.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java

and alter version can be found by downloading the source code and looking in

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous
```

package

So a reasonable attempt has already been made but rather difficult to work out which additional chars it covers that are not covered by the Normalizer method.

Comment: More recent link: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/5.2.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java#ASCIIFoldingFilter.foldToASCII(char[],int,char[],int,int)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can not be done in a generic fashion because the unicode standard does not always specify 'simpler' forms of each character, and in many cases it wouldn't even make sense to try.

If you look at a page like [LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm)  you will see what information the standard actually specifies for a given character.  (Look only at the block labeled *Unicode Data*.)

Notice that there *is* a Decomposition given into a different unicode sequence, however the character can be represented *either* as `\u00fc`, or `\u0075\u0308`.  You could mechanically convert instances of the first to the second and then strip all the combining marks, however...

Now look at something like [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DZE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0455/index.htm) and you'll see that while it is printed using something more or less exactly like `S`, it is in fact a completely different letter.  In fact the sound it makes is */dz/*.

If you *really* *really* wanted to do this, you would have to quite literally write a library with a database containing a mapping for every single character.  Some, like the first example above, you could do semi-automatically, but others like the second example have no real clear mapping.

Comment: Thanks but the question is about symbols and graphical chars NOT diacritics and such like, this part is already solved well enough for my purposes. The point is to provide a representation of the value that can be used in a filename so that is is more portable. Typically this function will be used by users who cannot pronounce or understand the original language, and in the graphical characters that is irrelevant anyway

Comment: @PaulTaylor: but the underlying *system* is the same. There is no 'generic' conversion of the kind you ask, so must create a conversion table yourself. Caskey correctly pointed that out in his last paragraph.

Comment: I'm surprised that either Im the first one to want this or that I'm not the first but none willing to share their custom conversion.

Comment: Welcome to the world of I18N. :-)  Also, pay special attention to the cyrillic example, there the glyph similarity has no bearing on the underlying consonant sound.  Sadly glyphs are glyphs, characters are characters and unicode only encodes characters.  Fonts encode glyphs.